# Remove highlighting from extjs combobox after selection

Tags: extjs, combobox

Whenever an item is selcted from extjs combobox, it gets highlighted as follows

[image]

Is there any way to remove this highlighting. I searched in google with no success.

I am using `ExtJs 2.3.0`

Comment: What's the ExtJS version?

Comment: @LaurentiuL. I am using ExtJs 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you really need to consider upgrading your ExtJS version. I haven't seen this behavior by default in the newer versions.

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox), in the config phase i don't see anythin which can help you.

The simplest thing you can do is add a `select` listener where you call the [`selectText` method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-method-selectText)

```
     comboBox.on('select', function(combo,record,index) {
        // set the cursor at the start
        //comboBox.selectText(0,0);
        var cursorEnd =combo.getValue().length;
        comboBox.selectText(cursorEnd,cursorEnd);
    });
```

[See working example  with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpj3r77k/4/). It uses a newer ExtJS for illustrative purposes, however the select event and selectText method are also available in ExtJS 2.3.

Comment: At least in 4.2.2, this behaviour is default as well, unless you define the combo as `editable:false`. Furthermore, upgrading may not be an option, since some components were removed between Ext3 and Ext4, just to be added again as - this time as an expensive upgrade - for Ext5. (Yes, I mean the `pivotgrid`.)

Comment: I recommend the upgrade. Whether that is practical or not it is for him to decide, even if in most projects it's not worth the upgrade. As for editable, it can be useful to combine it with forceSelection for searching values.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. Fiddle works very well but in my condition it is not working. Even if I forcefully set `comboBox.selectText(2,5);` it selects whole string

Comment: Do provide the relevant code (edit your question). Are you sure the select event gets triggered? Are you using the right args for the handler? You coul use the first argument as the comboBox.

Comment: I debugged the code and select even is getting triggered. Not sure why selectText is not working

Comment: Use a debug version of the extjs library and go inside it as well. It can be at times illuminating, maybe it's even a bug.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. It worked!!!! while debugging it was showing like not selecting text but when debugger is removed, it worked :) Thanks for help.